# Confidence inerval for Empirical Type I error simulation alpha = 0.05

Tags: confidence-interval, simulation, type-i-and-ii-errors

I'm doing a Type I error simulation(10,000 times) at alpha = 0.05. I wonder how can I calculate a confidence interval for the simulated restuls? At a 95% confidence interval, I suppose I can use xbar +- sqrt(sigma/N). I know the mean would be at 0.05, but what would be the sigma?

Comment: You have a proportion variable, right, number of rejections out of $10000$ opportunities? // Why is the mean $0.05?$

Comment: Multiple posts on site address this issue already. It's a straight binomial proportion, so you can use any of the binomial proportion CIs (there's a whole Wikipedia page of them) - but your n is large enough to just use the ordinary normal approximation for the standard error √[p(1-p)/n]

Comment: (Sorry, that should say 'with', not 'for' above).... Relevant information here on std errors and CIs for Monte Carlo rejection rates - Possible duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223664/confidence-interval-for-the-p-value-estimate-when-doing-monte-carlo-testing/ but you may find a better one

Comment: Note that if you want a 95% interval you don't go ±1 std error.